# How can I regenrate csrf token in laravel 5.2 by ajax, if token expire. but it returning alway same token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I regenerate csrf token in laravel 5.2 by ajax, if token expire. but it returning alway same token

```
Route::get('refresh-csrf', function(){
    return csrf_token();
    });


<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshToken(){
$.get('refresh-csrf').done(function(data){
$('input[name="_token"]').val(data); 
        });
    }
    setInterval(refreshToken, 15000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Laravel Caffeine](https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine).

It does exactly what you're after, by keeping forms alive and able to be submitted after being left to sit for extended periods of time and it works on all pages which have a `_token` field.